# How to display link description in a separate window

Tags: html, iframe

I am developing a webpage with a menu bar on the top (basically a table with a single row and the row items are my links..eg: Home, Gallery, Contact US). What I need is that when the user clicks on these links, the details/description/content should be displayed in a box (iframe) under this menu bar.

Currently what I am doing is I have an html page for each of the links.. and when the user clicks on the menu item, the corresponding html page opens up in the iframe. So far it is working well but I am wondering if there is any other way of doing this rather than having so an html page for each of the menu item?

Since I am having so many html pages for every menu item, does it make my webpage slow?

Comment: Are you familiar to PHP?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure what your getting at, but you could use PHP, checking for `isset($_POST['submit_button_name'])` using a series of submit buttons to query the correct results in the `iframe` or AJAX. Or you could write your results based JavaScript `onclick`. I would have to see your site.

Comment: Thank You! I do not know PHP... the site is built on based on HTML and CSS only. I have not published the site yet.. I am still developing it.